# Outlook (app) doesn't render the html of the email

Tags: node.js, outlook, smtp, nodemailer

I'm using nodemailer to verify the email of the user that signed-up to the website

[What it looks like on the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoVJj.png)

[What it looks like on the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL3wi.png)

Nodemailer options:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com",
    secureConnection: false,
    port: 587,
    tls:{
        ciphers:"SSLv3"
    },
    auth: {
        user: process.env.ACCOUNT_NAME,
        pass: process.env.ACCOUNT_PASS
    }
})
```

Function that sends email once the user has correctly entered the correct data:

```
function sendEmail(email,token){
    const mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.ACCOUNT_NAME,
        to: email,
        subject: "Vérifié votre email",
        html: '<html><body><form method="POST" action="https://test.com/verifEmail"><input type="hidden" value="'+token+'" id="IDtoken" name="IDtoken"/><input type="hidden" value="'+email+'" id="emailToken" name="emailToken"/><input value="Vérifiez votre email" type="submit"/></form></body></html>'
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,(error,info) =>{
        if (error){
            console.log('error');
        } else {
            console.log('this shit works '+info.response);
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't render buttons and forms. In order to make this functional, it's better to generate a link where the security token is in the link's parameters

```
function sendEmail(email, token, place, message) {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.ACCOUNT_NAME,
    to: email,
    subject: message,
    html: '<html><body><a href="https://test.com/'+place+'?token='+token+'&email='+email+'">'+message+'</a></body></html>'
  }

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('error');
    } else {
      console.log('this works '+info.response);
    }
  })
}
```